# diagnose I/O error on WD Blue SSD

Tags: lvm, io, e2fsck

I have a 1TB WD Blue SSD.  It has two partitions,

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: 2115            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8FF3A4A2-ACE0-4E7A-A9E4-29056B4BAD11

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdd2  1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux LVM
```

/dev/sdd2 has two logical volumes, a swap and an ext4 partition.

I tried to boot this SSD from USB and something went wrong.  Ever since then I can display the VG and LVs on /dev/sdd2 but I cannot mount the ext4 LV, nor access any data on either the swap or ext4 LV, with cat for example.

When I try to mount I get

```
can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

I have run

```
mke2fs -n /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
```

to get other superblocks and tried

```
e2fsck -b
```

but with no success

When I run

```
cat /dev/sdd2
```

I get characters but if I run

```
cat /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
cat /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
```

I get Input/output error

simialrly with dd or ddrescue I can recover data from /dev/sdd2, but not from /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1 nor /dev/ubuntu-vg/root.

I have run smartctl tests and my return values are always 0 which indicates no problems.

How can I diagnose the I/O error and/or fix these file systems?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with LVM. Try `vgck` to check the volume group.

Comment: I have run vgck and pvck but I am not getting any information back from them.  I have read the man pages but I must admit I still don't know if I am running them correctly. I have tried `vgck --updatemetadata ubuntu-vg`, `vgck --verbose ubuntu-vg`, `vgck --verbose -dddddd ubuntu-vg` and then read /var/log/syslog but and still non the wiser.  When I run `pvck --repair /de/sdd2` it reports "Command does not accept option: --repair" which seems to contradict the man page.  Do they automatically repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution from [LinuxTechi](https://www.linuxtechi.com/fixing-lvm-io-errors/). When my boot attempt failed I had to do a hard shutdown and this non-clean shutdown has caused a problem with LVM.

The solution:

```
# lvchange -an /dev/ubuntu-vg/root 
# lvchange -an /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1 
# vgchange -an ubuntu-vg
# vgchange -ay ubuntu-vg
# lvchange -ay /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
# lvchange -ay /dev/ubuntu-vg/roo
```

now it mounts just fine and I can read all the files